# Drop dataset rows based on another dataset column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

Been racking my brain trying to figure out a way todo this.

Ive got 2 datasets... one dataset contains a list of meetings based on the name of a committee. But a committee might be canceled, or not have a meeting purpose assigned to it. So i want to exclude those meetings. I have another dataset drawn from a table that contains meeting "purposes". So I want to eliminate the meetings from the first dataset not found in the second dataset. So of course, the first dataset is going to most likely be larger than the second dataset.. and all attempts ive made looping through both have failed because of this.

Can anyone toss me a code snippit that might help with this?

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried? Showing effort goes a long way towards receiving a good answer.

Comment: Would have to see what youve tried first, more info needed

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [DataRelation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad(v=vs.110).aspx), isn't it?

Comment: I think you're right Pradeep Kumar! So once I have the relation setup, I can just exclude rows from the first dataset not found in the second dataset?

Comment: Once i have the datarelation established between the two datasets - how do I drop the rows from the first set when the column key is not found in the second?

Comment: does anyone have any idea? please

Comment: Post your code. Where are you getting your dataset? Is it a database? how are you loading the data? how are you looping through it? --- You are essentially telling us your car isnt working, but not telling us what it's doing - then asking us to figure out how to fix it